# MAUI Button doesn't have text on initialize

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I am teaching myself MAUI and I've run into a weird snag... I have a CollectionView with a Data Template and in the template I have a label and a button and the button initializes to the width of the string I enter for it but doesn't display the text.  If I reload the page by switching to another tab it displays properly.  Here's an image which shows both after a "reload" and before:

[image: Weird short button next to a normal button]

Here's the xaml content for the page:

```xml
<ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <CollectionView x:Name="WorkerListView" ItemsSource ="{Binding  WorkersModel.Workers}"
                        Margin="5" SelectionMode="Single" 
                        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding WorkerListSelectionChangedCommand}"
                        SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference WorkerListView}}">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="0"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Button Text="{Binding CommandName}" Command="{Binding KillWorkerCommand}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            </CollectionView>
            <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Button Command="{Binding AddWorkerCommand}" Text="Start New Worker"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I've tried it with both a binding and vanilla text- both do the same thing.  I'm not sure how to force a refresh on the page, and I certainly don't want to have to do that in case the page takes a while to do so.  The button functions, and even disables itself on a timer, but it still doesn't draw the text correctly.  Is this a bug or just something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could be a bug, there still are some issues with layouts and rendering. Which platform did you try this on? Does this also happen on other platforms?

Comment: @ewerspej It only seems to happen on Windows.  I just tried emulating an android and the buttons draw fine.

Comment: Then it's probably a bug. Did you try setting specific WidthRequest and HeightRequest values?

Comment: @ewerspej That fixes it!  Great idea.  Just height request was enough.